# Questions about deduction the dual form of Frobenius's Theorem

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, vector-fields

I am reading Page 435, *General Relativity* by Wald.

Let $T^*\subset V^*$ be a subspace of the dual tangent space of a manifold, $W\subset V$ be the subspace of the tangent space annihilated by $T^*$, i.e. for every $\omega\in T^*$ and every $Y\in W$ we have $\omega_aY^a=0$.

Now the author says the [Frobenius's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_%28differential_topology%29) implies
$$
2Y^aZ^b\nabla_{[b}\omega_{a]}=0
$$
for every $Y,Z\in W$ and every $\omega\in T^*$.

Then the author claims it holds if and only if

> $$ \nabla_{[b}\omega_{a]}=\sum_{\alpha=1}^{n-m}\mu^\alpha_{[a}
> v^\alpha_{b]} $$ where each $v^\alpha$ is an arbitrary one-form and
>   each $\mu^\alpha\in T^*$

Can anyone explain to me why?

---

Also, the author later says

> $\nabla_{[a}\xi_{b]}=\xi_{[a}v_{b]}$ for some one-form $v$ if and only
>   if $\xi_{[a}\nabla_b\xi_{c]}=0$.

I can work out the "=>" part, but don't know why "<=" holds. Could anyone help?